# When using a text field, im trying to get the keyboard to go away in IOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am trying to make the number pad disappear in IOS. I have added the code below to accomplish this and it only kind of works. I have to select text or double press to get the keyboard to go away. Once I have done this, and I click back into the text box, then it works like it should.

```
- (IBAction)didBeginEditingPointsText:(id)sender
{
    self.tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self

                                                       action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tap];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.pointsText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tap];
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your desired workflow a little better? From the point of the view coming onscreen, what happens, what do you want to happen, and how is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your viewDidLoad

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.nameTextField action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```